# Swift 3 GCFloat to GCRect

Tags: swift3, ios10

I'm using this code piece in my Swift project.
The following code worked fine in Swift 2 but don't seem to work in Swift 3 anymore, it gives the following error:

**Cannot assign value of type '(CGFloat, CGFloat, Int, Int)' to type 'CGRect'**

```
 if plusLayer == nil {
        plusLayer = CALayer()
        let halfWidth: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.width / 2
        let halfHeight: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.height / 2
        let ds: CGFloat = sqrt(halfWidth * halfWidth / 2)
        let x: CGFloat = halfWidth + ds - 27 / 2
        let y: CGFloat = halfHeight - ds - 27 / 2
        plusLayer.frame = (x, y, 27, 27)
        plusLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill
        if let i = plusSignImage {
            plusLayer.contents = i.cgImage
        } else {
            plusSignImage = UIImage(named: "PlusSign", in: Bundle(for: self.dynamicType), compatibleWith: UITraitCollection(displayScale: UIScreen.main().scale))
            plusLayer.contents = plusSignImage!.cgImage
        }
        layer.addSublayer(plusLayer)
    }
```

Anyone knows how I can solve this issue? Help'd be really appreciated!

Thanks! :D

Comment: plusLayer.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, CGFloat(27), CGFloat(27))   works?

Comment: Are you sure this code worked with Swift 2? I can't get it to compile – you cannot assign a tuple to a struct. Use the initialiser `CGRect(x:x, y:y, width:27, height:27)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line `plusLayer.frame = (x, y, 27, 27)`

should be
`plusLayer.frame = (x, y, 27 as CGFloat, 27 as CGFloat)`

This is because the `CGRect` initializer expects 4 numbers with the same type. Take a look at the Xcode suggestions:
[image]

Comment: That gives this error:Cannot assign value of type 

    '(CGFloat, CGFloat, (CGFloat), (CGFloat))' (aka '(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)') to type 'CGRect'

Comment: @MatthijsOtterloo I've modified my answer to provide the correct solution and an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You need explicit casting of 27 (an `Int` type) to `CGFloat`:

```
plusLayer.frame = (x, y, 27 as CGFloat, 27 as CGFloat)
```

Answer (score 0):

as an old developer, let make some clearness:

a) casting is a powerful features of some languages, but it must be known in details

b) we can cast using "as", but is NOT the same as doing CGFloat(xx)

c) "as" must be used for type casting of objects.
(see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html
)
d) CGRectMake does work in swift 2.x/xcode 7.3

e) don't cast to double, simply use:

```
    let r = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 30, height: 40)
```

compiler will understand which of these method call:

```
public init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)
public init(x: Double, y: Double, width: Double, height: Double)
public init(x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int)
```

and will call the 3rd.

If You write:

```
    let d = 10.0
    let r2 = CGRect(x: d, y: 20, width: 30, height: 40)
```

it will call 2nd, as d is a Double.

my two cents.